# Emberjs latest version with Router Error: has no method 'finishPartial'

Tags: ember.js

I just updated to the version of EmberJS from [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/C7LrM/59/).

controllers/views:

```
App = Em.Application.create();

// Instantiated and wired up for you in App.initialize()
App.ApplicationController = Em.Controller.extend();
App.ApplicationView = Em.View.extend({
  templateName: 'application'
});
App.NavbarController = Em.Controller.extend();
App.NavbarView = Em.View.extend({
  templateName: 'navbar'
});
// Your stuff
App.HomeController = Em.Controller.extend({});
App.HomeView = Em.View.extend({
  templateName: 'home'
});

App.ProfileController = Em.Controller.extend({});
App.ProfileView = Em.View.extend({
  templateName: 'profile'
});

// Nested views in the profile
App.PostsController = Em.Controller.extend({});
App.PostsView = Em.View.extend({
  templateName: 'posts'
});

App.PhotosController = Em.Controller.extend({});
App.PhotosView = Em.View.extend({
  templateName: 'photos'
});
```

I've been using the new Router, but getting some weird behaviour and was hoping an update might sort it out, unfortunately I'm now getting the following Warning and Error:

```
WARNING: Computed properties will soon be cacheable by default. To enable this in your app, set ENV.CP_DEFAULT_CACHEABLE = true. vendor.js:54720
Uncaught TypeError: Object function () { return initMixin(this, arguments); } has no method 'finishPartial' vendor.js:42905
```

Anyone have any clue what might be going here?

Comment: Use the stack trace of the console to find the line in your code that triggers the error. Post both the code and the stack trace.

Comment: Hey Zack, the error is coming from the Ember library, it's difficult to tell where its coming from as all my js is compiled into one large vendor.js file. This is the method where it falls down:

'Ember.Mixin.finishPartial(this);'

Let me know if you need me to get something more detailed. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Taking your jsfiddle as a starting point, the only error I have is the use of Em.State instead of Em.Route for defining the router.

With the latest version of ember, you have to use Em.Route.

Comment: So kind of late back to this one, but thankfully this seems to have resolves itself with the an ember update. Thanks for the help guys.

Answer (score 0):

The error indicates that your code is trying to call a method on a function when you should be operating on the result of a function.. e.g `myFunction.finishPartial();` instead of `myFunction().finishParital();`

A quick google for Em.Mixin leads me to suggest this wild guess:

`Em.Mixin.create().finishPartial(this)`